# What's the difference between these 2 sorting methods?

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 sorting methods and would like to understand the difference between the two. One method does a comparison and returns an integer. The other substracts one element from another. Please help me understand the difference and which method is preferred.

```
const onSortByUpvotes = () => { 
  let sortedArr = [...articlesList]
  sortedArr.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.upvotes > b.upvotes) {return -1}
    if (b.upvotes < b.upvotes) { return 1}
      return 0
    })
    setArticleList(sortedArr)
}

const onSortByUpvotes = () => {
    articlesList.slice().sort((a, b) => {
        return a.upvotes - b.upvotes
    })
    setArticleList(sortedArr)
}
```

Comment: The second does not update state using the sorted array. `sortedArr` seems like a typo. Or you just forgot to assign it `const sortedArr = articlesList....`

Comment: @BrianThompson Right I forgot that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two work exactly the same, as the function only cares about whether the returned value is positive, negative, or zero.

> If compareFunction is supplied, all non-undefined array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function (all undefined elements are sorted to the end of the array, with no call to compareFunction). If a and b are two elements being compared, then:

> If compareFunction(a, b) returns less than 0, leave a and b unchanged.
> If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAScript standard only started guaranteeing this behavior in 2019, thus, older browsers may not respect this.
> If compareFunction(a, b) returns greater than 0, sort b before a.
> compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned, then the sort order is undefined.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

The two work exactly the same. Second Function are the implicit version of first function. Behind the seen second function works as first function.

> `articlesList.slice().sort((a, b) => { return a.upvotes - b.upvotes })`